# To find out a header and index of a particular value in a multi-columned dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a Pandas Dataframe which has boolean values in it's cells.
I want to find out the header and index of all cells in the dataframe where the value is `False` (Expected output is `header_index`)

```
df_sample=pandas.DataFrame([[True,True,False,True],[False,True,False,True],[True,True,True,True],[False,True,True,True]],columns=['ColumnA','ColumnB','ColumnC','ColumnD'])

   ColumnA  ColumnB  ColumnC  ColumnD
0     True     True    False     True
1    False     True    False     True
2     True     True     True     True
3    False     True     True     True
```

My expected output is:

```
ColumnC_0
ColumnA_1
ColumnC_1
```

I have tried multiple iterations using `loc` and `iloc` but unable to come up with this formatted output
A logical idea on how to approach this would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to reshape the dataframe `df_sample` into a `MultiIndex` series `s`, then use boolean masking to filter the series next use `map` to flatten the `MultiIndex` to get the desired list:

```
s = (~df_sample).stack()
idx = s[s].index.map(lambda s: f'{s[1]}_{s[0]}').tolist()
```

Result:

```
print(idx)
['ColumnC_0', 'ColumnA_1', 'ColumnC_1', 'ColumnA_3']
```